# Question about the expected value of random variable, using expected value properties

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

Suppose that the number of children N of a randomly chosen family satisfies

$P(N=n) = \dfrac{3}{5} \left(\dfrac{2}{5}\right)^n $

for $n=1,2,3 ...$

Now suppose that a child is equally likely to be a girl or a boy, and let X be the number of
daughters in a randomly chosen family.

I am trying to find $E[X]$  (By the way I found $E[N]=\frac{2}{3}$)

My initial thought is to use $E[X|N = n]$ Because, the number of daughters in family of $n$ children is the random variable $X$ and it is binomial distribution with parameter $n,p$ and as we know expected value in this case $\frac{1}{2}$ . Therefore our $E[X|N=n]=np=\frac{1}{2}$n

Now I am stuck here. I am thinking to use $E[E[X|N=n]]$ but I am not sure if this is appropriate for calculation $E[X]$.

Comment: This is the [law of total/iterated expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)

Comment: You need to expand the support to include $n=0$ as a possibility to get your distribution for the children to sum to $1$.  For the children you have a geometric distribution with parameter $p=\frac35$ while for the girls you have a geometric distribution with parameter $p=\frac34$ (similarly for the boys), with the expected number in each case being $\frac{1-p}{p}$.

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly correct.  Because the conditional variable $X \mid N = n$ is binomial with parameters $n$ and $p = 1/2$, you computed
$$\operatorname{E}[X \mid N] = N/2,$$
hence
$$\operatorname{E}[X] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[X \mid N]] = \operatorname{E}[N/2] = \operatorname{E}[N]/2.$$
What are your reservations regarding this approach?

Comment: My reservation was not actually due to any particular reason, but rather because I am still learning about the properties of random variables and their expectations. Given the depth and breadth of this forum, I wanted to consult you. Thank you for your answer.